# how to troubleshoot intermittent junit test failures?

Tags: dependency-injection, junit, isolation

I am dealing with a case where my tests pass or fail based on the order of declaration. This of-course points to not properly isolated tests. But I am stumped about how to go about finding the issue. 
The thing is my junit tests derive from a class that is belongs to a testing framework built on junit and has some dependency injection container. The container gets reset for every test by the base class setup and so there are no lingering objects at least in the container since the container itself is new. So I am leaning toward the following scenario.

1. test1 indirectly causes some classA which sets up classA.somestaticMember to xyz value. test obj does not maintain any references to classA directly- but classA is still loaded by vm with a value xyz when test1 ends.
2. test2 access classA and trips up on somestaticmember having xyz value.

The problem is a) I dont know if this is indeed the case- how do I go about finding that ? I cannot seem to find a reference to a static var in the code...
b) is there a way to tell junit to dump all its loaded classes and do it afresh for every test method ?

Comment: If your tests fail depending on order of execution, then they're not truly unit tests.  That, or you're not taking advantage of fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a method with `@Before`, like

```
@Before public void init()
{
    // set up stuff
}
```

and JUnit will run it before each test.  You can use that to set up a "fixture" (a known set of fresh objects, data, etc that your tests will work with independently of each other).

There's also an `@After`, that you can use to do any cleanup required *after* each test.  You don't normally need to do this, as Java will clean up any objects you used, but it could be useful for restoring outside objects (stuff you don't create and control) to a known state.

(Note, though: if you're relying on outside objects in order to do your tests, what you have isn't a unit test anymore.  You can't really say whether a failure is due to your code or the outside object, and that's one of the purposes of unit tests.)

Comment: I agree- its not a "unit" test. Its more of a functional/integration test since I am using full outside objects. However  I don't have much of a say in the matter. Just HAVING test has been a big improvement as opposed to none. I am using junit 3.8 and setup and teardown methods, but as for outside objects how do I reinitialize ?

Comment: @treefrog: Depends on your DI framework and/or your objects.  You need to be able to either replace the objects with known fresh ones, or "reset" the existing ones -- manually if necessary.  For example, if your outside object is a database, delete all the old data and then insert enough data to do all your tests with.  Or for files, remove the file or put it back or replace it with a known version.  For network stuff, close the connection and restart it.  The point is, *undo any side effects* your tests could cause -- the environment should be exactly the same for each test.

Comment: yes I understand that is what I need to do- I was looking for ways to accomplish that- does junit provide a way for me to specify a seperate class loader for loading tests ? or may be I need to iterate through all the classes loaded by the classloader and clean it up via reflection- I can't think of any other way